Why does LiteDB create a duplicate on update?
This operation will update the correct row, but will also create a duplicate of that row. How do I prevent this behavior ?
        public bool Update(UserModel entity)
        {
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_connectionString))
            {
                var col = db.GetCollection<UserModel>();
                var result = col.Update(entity);
                return result;
            }
        }

For reference, UserModel looks like this :
public class UserModel
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? UserName { get; set; }

    /* Some more fields without annotations*/
}

I've tried with and without the [BsonId] annotation.
Edit : Updated code after Fildor's suggestion that I need to use the instance that's already in the collection :
        public bool Update(UserModel entity)
        {
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_connectionString))
            {
                var col = db.GetCollection<UserModel>();
                var inCol = col.FindById(entity.Id);
                inCol.UserName = entity.UserName;
                return col.Update(inCol);
            }
        }

So I'm using the instance from the collection, but it still creates duplicates.

You need to attach the entity or set its state to modified. Otherwise the built in orm will treat it as new entity.

And how am I supposed to do that ? When I look at the Getting Started of LiteDB at https://www.litedb.org/docs/getting-started/ they don't seem to be doing anything special ?

Note how their example is using the same instance of the entity and collection for the update. The changetracker is aware in that example. Not in yours.

You can try this: retrieve the entity then mutate that instance and update it. All of which using the same db/collection instance.

What is the Id? You are aware, you cannot use 0, right?

I updated the question with code that uses the instance that's in the collection. Still duplicates :/
The Id is not 0.

I am going to try and reproduce ... just will take a good amount of time, since I cannot do that at work...

The code isn't enough to reproduce the problem. I can't reproduce this with the sample code in Getting Started. If Update caused duplicates, the example would produce duplicates too.

Please post enough code so others can compile it and reproduce the problem. In a database with a single customer, if I use var customer=col.FindById(1); cust.Name = "Other Name";col.Update(cust); I get only one result when I call col.FindAll().ToList();. If Update created duplicates I'd get 2

^^ Same cannot reproduce. As long as the Id is correect, it does what is expected.
